# ^ character not functioning as expected in bash regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, rm

I have a directory of test files labelled `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12` along with others labelled `ex1`, `ex2`, `ex3`, etc...

I tried to remove all files from this directory whose name doesn't include 'ex' using the following code:

```
rm [^a-z]
```

It was successful in removing all files labelled with a single digit, however files 10-12 still remain and I can't understand why.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Currently left in this directory are all files beginning with 'ex', and files labelled `10`, `11`, `12`. Upon using the command once again the following error message appears:

> rm: [^a-z]: No such file or directory

Comment: `[^a-z]` matches a single character, either `^` or the characters between a and z (lowercase English).  `!` is used in globbing for "not", `^` in regular expressions (inside square brackets).

Answer (score 3):

Filename matching in bash is done with [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), not regexs.

But you need extglobs for what you want to do.

```
shopt -s extglob
rm !(ex)*
```